# how to use less memory with react-native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, data-structures

I am wondering about how can I unset or clear the variable `values` after the function executions ends. I have base64 String about 300kb - 500kb. in a list of 100 items.

Is this a problem ? and can I remove the values of a variable after functions executions ends ?

```
function fun(){

  for(let i = 0; I < 100; I++){

    let base64Str = 'Large string 300kb - 500kb .... ';

    otherFunc(base64Str);

    // base64Str = null; can this help to save more memory ? or no
  
  }

}
```

Is it normal my above function?
or there is concerns ? can I clear the values of `base64Str`  ? or there is not any problem If don't clear it.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see what memory usage is *over time*? If resources are allocated but never freed and keeps growing then I'd be concerned about that, but if you see memory usage consistent with what is loaded then I'd say your code is probably fine. Do you have an actual issue running your app with the amount of memory it *is* consuming? For your question, does setting `base64Str` to null at the end of the loop save memory... no, not really, it just gets reassigned at the start of the loop. It may only be an issue if `otherFunc` holds on to object references.

Comment: Javascript uses a garbage collector, putting null in your example won't have any effect, as the next iteration of your loop is going to clear it anyway.  The only concern I would have with a loop like this is that there is no async going on, and this is likely were the GC will do most it's work.  I assume your getting the 300kb from somewhere, normally this would be async, so it's maybe not an issue.

Comment: actually I don't see any Issue I am just publishing my app, this was a concern for me, because that I asked if this is a concern then I should find a better way. because I think in every loop there is a `new variable with 300kb size` so may I have `100 x 300kb = 30000kb = 30mb memory` in any call.

Comment: and what about if I declare the `base64Str ` var, outside the `loop` ? can it be more efficient ?

Comment: @Belqis  No, its unlikely to have any effect, and is then more prone to errors due to scope,..   If you can keep scope local in JS it's can prevent strange errors, it's one of the main advantages of `let` and `const` compared to `var`